# Why we can't write python program in One line like other programming language?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Just using the below python code**

```
a = 1;while (a <= 5):print(a);a += 1;
```

Getting below error:

```
a = 1;while (a <= 5):print(a);a += 1;
          ^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

if i'm using below code then it's working fine:

```
a = 1;
while (a <= 5):print(a);a += 1;
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

If here Indentation is issue then why we are getting Syntax error ?

Comment: You can only use `;` to delimit line statements. `while` is not a line statement, it is a block statement (even if you put the block on the same line as the `while`).

Comment: @sagar-gautam, It's how python works; it cares about spaces and indentations, and some others don't. e.g. you can condense a thousand lines of a program in one line in JS, but programming languages are different.

Answer (score 2):

Python does allow [statement lists](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html):

```
stmt_list     ::=  simple_stmt (";" simple_stmt)* [";"]
```

However, as you can see they only allow [simple statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html), which do not include `while` statements:

```
simple_stmt ::=  expression_stmt
                 | assert_stmt
                 | assignment_stmt
                 | augmented_assignment_stmt
                 | annotated_assignment_stmt
                 | pass_stmt
                 | del_stmt
                 | return_stmt
                 | yield_stmt
                 | raise_stmt
                 | break_stmt
                 | continue_stmt
                 | import_stmt
                 | future_stmt
                 | global_stmt
                 | nonlocal_stmt
```

While statement is a compound statement.

```
compound_stmt ::=  if_stmt
                   | while_stmt  <==
                   | for_stmt
                   | try_stmt
                   | with_stmt
                   | match_stmt
                   | funcdef
                   | classdef
                   | async_with_stmt
                   | async_for_stmt
                   | async_funcdef
```